# railsのエラーSprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Devise::Registrations#newについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsでアプリ作成時に次のようなエラーにかかってしまい分からなかったので質問します。

調べたらプリコンパイルをしなきゃいけないなど `rails asset:compile` を実行したりsprocketをupdateしましたが同じでした。
他にも文字間違いなどがないか確認しましたが見当たらずで数時間てこずっています。
私的にはtemplate(文法?)とも気になるのですがどなたか原因のわかる方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか？

**エラー:**

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Devise::Registrations#new
Showing /Users/hiratashinichi/recipe-site/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #10 raised:

The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.
Extracted source (around line #10):
8
9
10
11
12
13
              
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>

<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track':'reload' %>    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

以下の記事が参考になるように思います（No.9の回答）。application.cssというファイル名が衝突しているのではないか？というものです。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46004615/stylesheet-pack-tag-not-finding-app-javascript-src-application-css-in-rails-5-1

見当違いでしたらすみません。ご参考まで。

Comment: 解答ありがとう御座います。
一応apprication.html.erbのなかの<Stylesheet link tag apprication media all～を一度消して実行するとエラーが消えて本来作成しているアプリのページに切り替わることができたのですが、その後new.htmlにてソースコードを記述してリロードしましても何故かCSSの機能(色、画面の中央よせ)などが反映されていなかったんでプリコンパイルの他にもCSSの設定で何か見落としも考えられますでしょうか？

Comment: 原因を探していたらapplication.html.erbにbulmaのcdnである<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma/css/bulma.min.css">を記述すればエラーなく表示できました。結果としてはプリコンパイルよりbulmaの問題だったと感じています。回答ありがとうございます。

Comment: 根本的な解決ではないように思います…。エラーによると Sprockets を使うようになっていると思います。この場合は、CSSをアタッチには stylesheet_link_tag を使います。なので、stylesheet_pack_tag では application.css の読み込みができないのでしょう（The asset "application.css" is not present in the asset pipeline.
Extracted source）。

Comment: Webpacker を使うのでしたら、一度、Rails ガイドを確認されることをお勧めします。https://railsguides.jp/webpacker.html